# can't call parent function in child of zend_action_controller

Tags: zend-framework, action

I have the following class hierarchy and functions

```
abstract class Client_Controller_Abstract extends Zend_Controller_Action
abstract class Client_Tool_Controller_Abstract extends Client_Controller_Abstract
class Module_controller extends Client_Tool_Controller_Abstract
{

    public function util()
    {
    }

    public function sampleAction()
    {
        $this->util();
    }
}
```

I would like to move function util to Client_Tool_Controller_Abstract, so I can share it in other controllers. However when I do this I get:

```
Method "util" does not exist and was not trapped in __call()
```

This is Zend Framework 1.12

Comment: Please post all classes

Comment: I have similar setups and it's basic OOP so it should work. However I remember having this same issue but that was simply me working in the wrong file(s) b/c I had some weird project setup with duplicate folders for various purposes. Thankfully my IDE was smart enough and told me in the class hierarchy that I was working in the wrong file.